# Copy array N times to a flatted array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've an array of four elements and I want to copy it to another array four times and I've done it by concatenating four times.

**My efforts**

```
let demoProperties = []
  .concat(fourDemoProperties)
  .concat(fourDemoProperties)
  .concat(fourDemoProperties)
  .concat(fourDemoProperties);
```

I also followed another [**way**](https://jsfiddle.net/4f3wgrzf/) (map and reduce) but this way iterate two times.

Have there any easiest optimum way to copy N times? Any of your suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the spread syntax:

```
const demoProperties = [...fourDemoProperties, ...fourDemoProperties, ...fourDemoProperties, ...fourDemoProperties];
```

Or use Array#fill to duplicate the array, and then use spread syntax with Array#concat to get a new array:

```js
const fourDemoProperties = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const demoProperties = [].concat(...Array(4).fill(fourDemoProperties));

console.log(demoProperties);
```

**Note:** both the manual an the Array#fill are shallow clones. If the items are objects, you'll clone the reference to the objects, and if you'll change one of them, the "copies" will change as well.

Example (check the browser's console):

```js
const fourDemoProperties = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];

const demoProperties = [...fourDemoProperties, ...fourDemoProperties, ...fourDemoProperties, ...fourDemoProperties];

demoProperties[0].a = 5000;

console.log(demoProperties);
```

Answer (score 1):

How you do it depend if you want to keep the reference among the sub arrays or not.

```js
var ar  = [1,2,3,4],
    ars = Array.from({length:4}).map(_ => ar),
    brs = Array.from({length:4}).map(_ => ar.slice());
console.log(ars);
console.log(brs);
```